# Blackberry Java ConnectionFactory unavailable

Tags: java, blackberry, httpconnection

I'm testing an application in a Pearl 9100. My app uses ConnectionFactory in order to get an available connection an perform an HTTP request.

I'm setting up the ConnectionFactory like this

protected int[] preferredTransportTypes = { TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, 
TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR };

protected int[] disallowedTransportTypes = { TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, 
TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP, 
TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2 };

Because I cannot use WAP or WAP2. Then I open the connection like this:

ConnectionDescriptor connd = cf.getConnection(url);

conn = (HttpConnection) connd.getConnection();

If I set WiFi ON and conneted to a WiFi Network, everything goes fine. But If I only leave the Mobile Network using 3G, the variable "connd" is Null when passing line number 1.

Why can this be possible?

Which should be the standard transport for a 3rd party app that wants to use the internet service?

Thanks!

Ezequiel

Answer (score 0):

> Why can this be possible?

Do you have your APN settings configured on device? They are wireless provider specific. Try googling on "BlackBerry APN settings " to find those settings.

> Which should be the standard transport for a 3rd party app that wants to use the internet service?

Unfortunatelly, there is no simple answer. It depends, as they say. Check this [tutorial](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742?name=NetworkingTransportsII) for best practices and ideas. In the tutorial there is an approach on what transports and in what order to support.